# Multiple lines one below the other

Tags: rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can LaTeX be used to make a sheet of blank lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24512/can-latex-be-used-to-make-a-sheet-of-blank-lines)

I try to create horizontal lines so that students exercise book to write the answer. I can not understand why the following command does not work.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,svgnames,11pt]{book}

\begin{document}
 \hrulefill{}  \\
 \hrulefill{}  \\
 \hrulefill{}  \\
 \hrulefill{}  \\
\end{document}
```

Then I writing like this and everything is okay.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,svgnames,11pt]{book}

\begin{document}
 \phantom{.} \hrulefill{} \smallskip \\
 \phantom{.} \hrulefill{} \smallskip \\
 \phantom{.} \hrulefill{} \smallskip \\
 \phantom{.} \hrulefill{} \smallskip \\
\end{document}
```

but this does not satisfy me to write a few simple lines one below the other.

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24512/can-latex-be-used-to-make-a-sheet-of-blank-lines) help?

Comment: @egreg I think we're pretty close to what I want

Comment: If they directly solve your problem, then leave a comment so the question can be closed as duplicate; if the solution you find is substantially different, then you can self-answer; if you aren't able to find a solution, then let us know by adding to your question.

Comment: \fillwithlines{2in} does not work for me there is a package for this? I compiled with xelatex

Comment: The `\fillwithlines` is a command of the `exam` class, so not for general use. Probably my own is better for you; I'll add a complete example with the result.

Comment: @egreg yes would prefer this but with book class :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `\null`:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,svgnames,11pt]{book}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \null\hrulefill{}  \\
    \null\hrulefill{}  \\
    \null\hrulefill{}  \\
    \null\hrulefill{}  \\
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: Lines]

Comment: thanks this works well but I'm trying to make fillwithlines{1in} to  work

Comment: @egreg suggested that a good thing but I can not make it work